# How to add built-in rules in user group policies?

Tags: content-hub

Any idea how can we add built-in rules in `user group policies` of content hub?

There are few built-in rules added in our `content hub` production instance and I just wanted to replicate them in our lower environment, but could not find how to do that.

Screenshot of built in rule(Production).

[image]

**Note: These built-in rules are not allowing me to update any check boxes.**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out.

**You can not add these rules directly into the user group policies, These are automatically created when you add users/groups to a collection.**

Ex: When you go to a collection page there is a link called `User access` at top right of the page.

[image]

Once you click on it, it will open a popup and give you the option to add `user/user groups` who can access this collection.

[image]

Once you add any user group, these inbuilt rule will be added to that user group policies automatically.